# imageview click listener still works after scale down size with tween animation

Tags: java, android, android-animation

whit this tween animation instructions i change an imageview size to 0 and after that it disappers:

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="400"
android:fromXScale="1"
android:fromYScale="1"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toXScale="0"
android:toYScale="0" />
```

but my problem is, after disappearing, my image view still clickable and clicklistener works!! i want to scale down image view and disappear it and click doesntwork too. why this happen? how can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is at animationEnd set the imageView visibility to GONE.

Comment: i do this: askbtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure that the click listener is set on the imageview and not on its container.